# Automatically download JS Window.print() as PDF file or configure jsPDF to get Window.print() result?

Tags: javascript, pdf, printing, pdf-generation, jspdf

My goal is to create and download PDF based on HTML content.
Window.print() does it in really nice way. E.g. it splits table content between pages like a boss

[image]

while jsPDF with autoPaging, split it like this(as you can see it splits image between two pages, doesn't create new table header for each page)

[image]

So my first question is, is it possible to automatically download Window.print() result PDF file? If no, is it possible to configure jsPDF to get PDF file like Window.print() makes?